# Apply values on a list of functions

Tags: r

I have a list, which contains 100 functions as each element. each function accepts 2 values as an input. I have another object as which is 100X2 matrix, first element of the first row is the value for first input to pass to the function and similarly to second value. now I want to pass the values and get the output from the function, is there any efficient way to do it with apply functions

Comment: Yes.  Please provide a minimal, reproducible example of what you have in mind and somebody will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
flist <- list(min, max, sum)

x <- matrix(1:6, ncol = 2)
y <- lapply(1:nrow(x), function(i) list(x[i,1], x[i,2]))

mapply(do.call, flist, y)
```